# Unique index into a subdocument list, indexed by one key

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i need to know if is possible to have a list of objects, where the objects are  uniques by day.

I have a collection with this format:

```
{
  domain: "google.com"
  counters: [
    { day: "2011-08-03", metric1: 10, metric_2: 15 }
    { day: "2011-08-04", metric1: 08, metric_2: 07 }
    { day: "2011-08-05", metric1: 20, metric_2: 150 }
  ]
}
```

I tried something like that:

```
db.test.ensureIndex({ domain: 1, 'counters.day': 1 }, { unique: true }).
```

with **upsert** and **$push**, but this not works.

Then I tried with **upsert** and **$addToSet**. but i can't set the unique fields.

I need to push a new counter, if the day exists, it should be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique indexes working only for the root document, but not for the embedded. So that's mean that you can't insert two documents with same domain and counters.day. But you can insert into embedded `counters` duplicated rows.

> I need to push a new counter, if the day exists, it should be
>   replaced.

When you trying to insert new embedded document you should check if document with such day exists and in case if it exists make an update, otherwise insert.

Comment: Can you do it in one go? What if you check, it is OK, but before you insert someone else makes an insert?